# List View Row Formatting Using Ratings Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, formatting, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint Online list that contains the standard like style ratings feature.  I am trying to format a row view for this list, I can get everything to work except for the ratings column (I can't get anything from it to display).  Any ideas how I can format the JSON of the list view to display the information contained in the ratings column and allow the out of the box functionality to work (liking, removing like, displaying number of likes on the row)?  Screenshots of the list and the relevant section of JSON are below.

Unformatted list:
[image: Unformatted list]

Formatted List Row (trying to have it display in the bottom right):
[image: Formatted List]

```
        {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "attributes": {
              "class": ""
            },
            "txtContent": "Number of Likes: "
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
              "display": "inline-block",
              "text-transform": "capitalize"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Number_x0020_of_x0020_Likes]"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but as of now only the following columns types supports JSON formatting:

- Calculated
- Choice
- ContentType
- Counter (ID)
- Currency*
- Date/Time
- Hyperlink
- Location*
- Lookup
- Multi-Choice
- Multi-Line Text
- Multi-Person
- Number
- Person or Group
- Picture
- Single line of text
- Title (in Lists)
- Yes/No
- Formats for these column types can only be applied through Field Settings.

**official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types).